# SELECT Count(userid) adjusment

Tags: mysql

My statement shows result as

```
   userid    Count(userid)

  SELECT userid, COUNT( userid ) 
   FROM friends
   GROUP BY userid
   ORDER BY  `COUNT(userid)` DESC 
   LIMIT 0 , 30
```

I have 1 more column "level" in friends table need to add it in my result
how tp adjust my statement

So my result appear like

```
   userid    Count(userid)   level
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Since there seem to be more than one row in `friends` (and thus more than one `level`) per userid, you need to specify which `level` to display. Max?

Comment: -1, you have to google before you asking such questions , have you tried "SELECT userid, COUNT(userid), level .... FROM"

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson, It seems that he is talking only about displaying the column, nothing complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try :

```
   SELECT userid, COUNT( userid ) AS cnt, level
   FROM friends
   GROUP BY userid
   ORDER BY cnt DESC 
   LIMIT 30
```